# PHP Script Version Checking/Notification

Tags: php

How can I check the version of my script against an online file to see if it's the latest version?

*For clarification, I'm talking about a script I wrote, not the version of PHP. I'd like to incorporate a way for the end user to tell when I've updated the script.*

Comment: You should maybe rephrase the question to make it clear if you want the version of the script you are running or the PHP_VERSION

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To specify the second (more simple) solution [phjr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236070/php-version-checking#236098) proposed:

Have a file `version.txt` on your own public server and include the following function into your deployed project/script:

```
define('REMOTE_VERSION', 'http://your.public.server/version.txt');

// this is the version of the deployed script
define('VERSION', '1.0.1');

function isUpToDate()
{
    $remoteVersion=trim(file_get_contents(REMOTE_VERSION));
    return version_compare(VERSION, $remoteVersion, 'ge');
}
```

`version.txt` should just contain the most recent version number, e.g.:

```
1.0.2
```

Comment: I am out of votes for the next 15 hours but want to upvote this answer.

Comment: Another solution that sounds great, I'll try this one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Per comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236070/php-version-checking#236084)

```
// Substitue path to script with the version information in place of __FILE__ if necessary
$script = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
$version = SOME_SENSIBLE_DEFAULT_IN_CASE_OF_FAILURE;
if(preg_match('/<!-- Script version (\d*(\.\d+)*) -->/', $script, $version_match)) {
    $version = $version_match[1];
}
```

Comment: I like that... I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

```
define('REMOTE_VERSION', 'http://your.public.server/version.txt');
define('VERSION', '1.0.1');
$script = file_get_contents(REMOTE_VERSION);
$version = VERSION;
if($version == $script) {
    echo "<div class=success> 
<p>You have the latest version!</p> 
</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class=error> 
<p>There is a update available!</p> 
</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have an RSS or Atom **feed** with update info. Wordpress does something similar. Then you can locally save information which updates have been shown to the user etc.

For even simpler solution, have a file on project website that would contain just the version number. Then compare it with a version number stored in your program, probably within a constant.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
if($version == $script)
```

to

```
if($version >= $script)`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).