# How to have a PHP Website tool with a version check

Tags: php, html, version

So I work on a small php website tool that a few people use and what I'm looking to have added is a little version checker in it. The tool is normally hosted by others on different servers/domains/whatever have you so I'm having a bit of a trouble figuring out how I can accomplish this and do so in the best possible method.

So what I'm looking to do is have a webpage that just has a number on it which is the latest version. Lets say 3.2.2 is displayed on www.myawesomephptool.com/version.html in some way shape or form . Now on their installation when they open up their admin page it pulls in that 3.2.2 as the latest version to see if they are on that version. So trying to keep it simple on requirements too.

Thanks for any help or suggestions,

Sara

Comment: Dear Mark Trapp, how about you spend more time being useful by answering questions then going through posts deleting people trying to give a little common courtesy while asking a question. You just make SO lifeless by doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a page on your site that returns the latest version, then the tool checks that page and compares it with the inbuilt version number.

sample code here: [PHP Script Version Checking/Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236070/php-script-version-checking-notification)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for.